# Different DB connection for individual model depending on environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Model (MessageImporter) that connects to a different Database than the other models using `self.establish_connection`. Everything works fine when I pass the connection info hardcoded. Now I need the connection to depend on the current environment. So I added the info to my `application_config.yml` (it's a simple nifty_config). I got stuck at how to pass the connection info to `self.establish_connection`.

Here's my current code:

```
class MessageImporter < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.establish_connection lambda {{
    :adapter => APP_CONFIG[:external_messages][:adapter],
    :host => APP_CONFIG[:external_messages][:host],
    :database => APP_CONFIG[:external_messages][:database],
    :username => APP_CONFIG[:external_messages][:username],
    :password => APP_CONFIG[:external_messages][:password]
  }}

# […]
```

I get an `undefined method 'symbolize_keys' for #<Proc:0x2564224>`-. Error I also tried it without the lambda, but that does not work either and I get an even weirder error:

```
Please install the  adapter: `gem install activerecord--adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/_adapter)
```

Or is there a better/Rails-ish way to set a different db-connection for individual models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Little different approach and it works:

Adding the connection info to the regular `database.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: […]
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

  message_import:
    adapter: mysql
    encoding: utf8
    username: […]
    password: […]
    database: […]
    host: […]
```

Note the nesting! `message_import` ist nested beneath `development`.

Within the `message_importer.rb`:

```
class MessageImporter < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection configurations[RAILS_ENV]['message_import']
```

Still wondering why my first approach didn't work but this does just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002364), the `establish_connection` method accepts a hash as input. Did you try this?—

```
class MessageImporter < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection {
    :adapter => APP_CONFIG[:external_messages][:adapter],
    :host => APP_CONFIG[:external_messages][:host],
    :database => APP_CONFIG[:external_messages][:database],
    :username => APP_CONFIG[:external_messages][:username],
    :password => APP_CONFIG[:external_messages][:password]
  }
```

Comment: Jup, i tried it. But with that code i even get Syntax-Errors: http://pastie.org/768685

Comment: What happens if you replace the symbols in the hash with strings, so `:adapter => APP_CONFIG['external_messages']['adapter']` etc?

Comment: That gives me an `You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
`-Error. Found a solution will post it in a sec.

Comment: 8 years later... that is indeed a syntax error, as the interpreter thinks you are starting a block, not passing a hash. If you want to pass a hash, use explicit parentheses `establish_connection({ ... })` (now the hash curlies are optional).